# Respect exactly the resource string for white-spacing and newlines

Tags: html, css, textarea, newline, whitespace

(I simply the question I asked previously in this thread).

I am trying to configure a textarea in HTML. And I want it to do exactly what the resource string tells about white-spacing and newlines (except wrapping).

For example, given a string `1234,\n  5678, 1234567890123456789\n  123`. `\n` means going to a newline, and space means a white spacing. Thus, i want it to be printed in the textarea as follows:

```
1234,
  5678, 12345678901234
56789
  123
```

Note that `1234567890123456789` is wrapped, because it reaches the max width of the textarea. It is totally normal, and what I expected.

However, my current code does not give the right output, here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body class="ms-font-m">
    <textarea id="myTextarea" style="font-size: 16px; font-family: monospace; height: 15em; resize: none; white-space: pre-line;"></textarea>
    <script>
        document.getElementById("myTextarea").value = "1234,\n  5678, 1234567890123456789\n  123"
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the result:

[image]

Does anyone know how to amend the code such that it prints what I expected?

PS: the whole [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/cofisu/edit?html,output)

PS: I tried all the keywords of `white-space` in this [page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space), no one gives me the satisfactory result...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>*[Original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/37445233/1):* An approach of how to resize the `textarea` `width` so the content will be contained in their rows respectively without overflow but respecting the breakpoints `\n`.</sub>

---

In my original answer I misunderstood what do you mean. After the feedback I noticed that I was wrong on what I was doing so here is the solution for your problem.

If you want that the words breaks into the next line when they overflows and respecting the spaces at the same time you just have to remove `white-space: pre-line;` and add `word-break: break-all;` property.

```js
document.getElementById("myTextarea").value = "1234,\n  5678, 1234567890123456789\n  123"
```

```css
#myTextarea{
  font-size: 16px; 
  font-family: monospace; 
  height: 15em; 
  resize: none;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="myTextarea" style=""></textarea>
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed comment, but clicking `Run code snippet` does not show what I expected in the OP. Is it normal?

Comment: @SoftTimur But in your question you want to show the text taking as reference the spaces and the breakpoints. Is it right? How is different when you click on `Run code snippet`?

Comment: The layout I want is specified in the beginning of the OP: I want `12345678901234` to follow `5678` in the same line, and `56789` goes to another line because of the pre-fixed width of the textarea and the wrapping. `Run code snippet` of your code is quite different from this...

Comment: @SoftTimur The difference is between the string that you have put and the expected output. When you put `1234,\n  5678, 1234567890123456789\n  123` you only will get 3 lines, as my result.

Comment: @SoftTimur But do not worry I will add your 56789 in the string to get the expected output :)

Comment: Sorry, `56789` is the last part of `1234567890123456789`. Maybe I was not clear in the title. Actually, I want ONLY 2 things that can make a newline: an explicit `\n`; or when a long string as `1234567890123456789` reaches the edge of the textarea, we wrap it.

Comment: @SoftTimur Oh, now I notice it. My god. I think I made the problem bigger.  Now I cannot spend a lot of time solving it because I have some things to do but I will search a workaround as soon as possible.

Comment: @SoftTimur Look at my edited answer. I think now is the expected result :)

Comment: The result looks good... and I think we don't have to remove `resize: none;`, no?

Comment: @SoftTimur That's true. Now fixed so the user will not resize the `textarea`.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear it is going unto the next line because of the font the size of the letters or the width size but I'm not getting the output you get, it doesn't go unto the next line. With a width of 20em it doesn't work but with 18em it does. Do you want to have the large text of DDDDDD.... be allowed to be scrolled or not wrap? Use white-space: nowrap; instead of pre-line.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
    <title>Title</title>  
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <link href="Office.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/office.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="Common.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="Notification.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Home.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/fabric/1.0/fabric.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/fabric/1.0/fabric.components.min.css">
    <style>
    .ms-TextField.ms-TextField--multiline .ms-TextField-field {
    font-family: monospace;
    height: 15em; 
    resize: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 10em;
    overflow: hidden;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body class="ms-font-m">
    <div id="content-main">
    <div class="padding">
    <div class="ms-TextField ms-TextField--multiline">
        <textarea class="ms-TextField-field" id="myTextarea" spellcheck=false style="font-size: 16px;"></textarea>
    </div>
    <script>
        document.getElementById("myTextarea").value = "=AAAA,\n  BBBB, DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD\n  CCCC"
    </script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's a bit low quality answer. This should rather be a comment. You don't yet have enough rep. to comment but if you edit and improve this answer  you probably get upvoted or accepted.

Comment: I want `DDDDD...` to be wrapped rather than scrolled... how could we do that?